# Make selenium Choose From the input box a number python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, select

I want Selenium to choose an option but it didn't work for me
I tried this

```
phone = Select(driver.find_element(By.NAME, "PhoneCountry"))
phone.select_by_data-value(self, US)
```

and it failed

And this is the html

[HTML of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddGpa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

```
Select(driver.find_element_by_id("PhoneCountry")).select_by_visible_text(u"United States ‏(‎+1)")
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such way to select option `by_data-value`.
There only 3 ways:

1. Select by index
2. Select by visible text
3. Select by value.

References:
[official documentations](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html)
[www.geeksforgeeks.org](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/selecting-a-drop-down-list-by-using-the-selenium-select_by_visible_text-method-in-python/)

So, instead of your code please try this:

```py
phone = Select(driver.find_element(By.NAME, "PhoneCountry"))
phone.select_by_visible_text(self, "US")
```

I don't know what is the actual visible text there, it can be "US", or "USA" or something else.

Comment: didn't work for me

This is the site
https://signup.live.com/signup?lcid=1033&wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=13&ct=1665419885&rver=7.0.6738.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https%3a%2f%2faccount.microsoft.com%2fauth%2fcomplete-signin%3fru%3dhttps%253A%252F%252Faccount.microsoft.com%252F%253Frefp%253Dsignedout-index%2526refd%253Dwww.google.com&lc=1033&id=292666&lw=1&fl=easi2&mkt=en-US&lic=1&uaid=27e17b2a5e3c4c2d85e4721d8c2d94ec

I want to choose from the list a number

Thank you

Comment: The link you shared doesn't contain any Select / drop list. Maybe it is on some more advanced step of creating Microsoft account?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to tell you, you should press (Use a phone number instead)

Comment: I see.. I tried, so far with no success.. I will try again later. That's interesting! In case you got a solution before me - please let me know